# Corregir error 132 vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access

He creado un récord set para importar fechas de una tabla. El problema es que cuando encuentra el campo vacío me da un error 132 No coinciden los tipos. Alguien dispone de una solución ¿
Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar tu código? De todas formas si tienes detectado el error, quizás puedas hacer control de errores en tu código y corregirlo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.